# Tracking event in Google Analytics - onclick

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, event-tracking

I have problem with events tracking in Google Analytics.

In site code I have implemented GA Universal tracking code:

```
    <script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-xx', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

I want to measure clicks on links so I used a onClick code.

```
<a href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'mobile', 'click to call', 'clicks');">Anchor</a>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I don't know why. I tried also previous formula (gaq)

```
<a href="http://www.link.com" target="_blank" onclick="ga('send', 'mobile', 'click to call', 'clicks');">Anchor</a>
```

But both of codes doesn't work.

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter to ga send is supposed to be the interaction type. I don't think "mobile" is an interaction type recognized by GA (should be "pageview" or "event" etc.).

Calling _gaq (btw. you pasted the same example twice) would not work at all with Universal Analytics code.

I suspect you want to send an event. Proper syntax would look like:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'mobile', 'click to call', 'clicks');"
```

Where the parameters, in sequence, are call to the send method, interaction type, event category, event action and event label (all strings). You could pass an additional numeric parameter for the event value if you want to assign a monetary value to your events (that would become part of the ROI calculations if you use Google Adwords).

Answer (score 0):

```
ga('send', 'event', 'mobile', 'click to call', 'clicks');"
```

Doesn't work. In Real Time repports>events Analytics doesn't track events.